# Memory dump with specific time information

Tags: kernel, ram

I want to dump the status of my memory (cache, RAM and swap) -- because I want to check something that happened yesterday -- but with time information. How can I dump that?

Comment: Unless you already had something setup to monitor something, that information is lost.